# Recursive fibonacci in IA32 assembly implementation

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86

I currently have the following code for recursively calculating the nth term of the fibonacci sequence in assembly, however it is not working appropriately (only works for the first 3 terms). Could anyone provide any insight?

```
pushl %ebp 
movl %esp,%ebp
movl 8(%ebp),%eax        #retrieve argument passed to function in eax
cmpl $1,%eax             #identify if its base case     
jle fin  
decl %eax               
pushl %eax               #push n-1 to stack for next function call
call _fibonacci         
movl %eax,%ecx           #store fib(n-1) in ecx
movl 8(%ebp),%eax        
subl $2,%eax
pushl %eax              #push n-2 to stack for next function call
call _fibonacci
addl %ecx,%eax          #add fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)
fin:                    #end label
movl %ebp,%esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: What debugging efforts have you made so far?  For instance, did you try single-stepping the code in your debugger and observe something about where the results go wrong?  Any such information would help people pinpoint the bug faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
call _fibonacci
addl %ecx,%eax          #add fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)
```

Your `_fibonacci` function uses `%ecx` without saving it (in the non-base case), so the recursive call  overwrites the value in `%ecx`.

You should save the returned value from the first call to `_fibonacci` on the stack instead of in a register.